# rails 7.0.4にてrails コマンドをするとinvalid byte sequence in UTF-8エラーが出て、何を調べればいいかわからない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-10

環境

- windows10 HOME
- ralis 7.0.4
- Ruby 3.1.2p20

rails sやrails -v, rails -h等のコマンド実行時に以下のエラーがでます。

```
C:\Users\ミナ\Desktop\プログラミング\enviroment\hello_app>rails s
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:51:in `match?': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:51:in `chop_basename'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:375:in `plus'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:355:in `+'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/pathname.rb:421:in `join'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/settings.rb:445:in `global_config_file'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/settings.rb:93:in `initialize'        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:332:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:332:in `settings'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:101:in `configured_bundle_path'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:97:in `bundle_path'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:641:in `configure_gem_home_and_path'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:83:in `configure'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:196:in `definition'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler.rb:145:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ミナ/Desktop/プログラミング/enviroment/hello_app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

した事

- "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8　rails s"等で検索し関連記事を見るも記事ごとに問題がまちまちで具体的に自分の場合はどうすればいいかわかりませんでした。
- 一つ目のエラーの指定先？のpathname.rbの行頭に"encoding: UTF-8"と追加してみましたがそれに対してsyntaxエラーがでました。

前提知識として何を学べばこのエラーを解決する糸口になるかご教示お願いします。
あるいはRubyやRailsのバージョンの問題なのでしょうか？
全くの初学者で、初歩的な質問をしてしまっていたら申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すぐに再現できる環境がないためログからの推量となりますが

おそらく `C:\Users\ミナ\Desktop\プログラミング\enviroment\hello_app` を `C:\hello_app` あたりにコピーして、そちらで `C:\hello_app>rails s` すると動くのではないでしょうか

---

ご提示のログから pathname ライブラリのメソッド `chop_basename` の実行中に `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)` が起きたことがわかります

[pathname は名前の通りパス名を扱うライブラリです](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/library/pathname.html)

よってパス名の処理中に問題が起きたことが推測されます

OS を問わず、マルチバイト（や空白混じり）のパスは処理に難があることが少なくありませんので、可能であればそういったマルチバイトや空白の混じらないパスで試されるとよいかと思います

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Users\ミナ\Desktop\プログラミング\enviroment\hello_app>

「ミナ」「プログラミング」などパスに日本語を含むディレクトリで作業しています。
日本語が混じっていると不具合が発生する可能性があります。
パスが半角英数字だけで表せるディレクトリで作業してみてください。